# Buffered Images not rendering when project is built as an executable jar file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, bufferedimage, executable-jar

So, I'm working on a 2D tile based game for my programming class. I've gotten the basics done with rendering images and moving in game. All my images work when I run the project in eclipse. When I build it as an executable jar file, none of the images show up.

This is what it should look like (when I run it in eclipse with my current set up)
[What is should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nAb5.jpg)

This is what happens when I run the executable jar.[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTvnp.jpg)

My images are loaded in assets class like so:

```
SpriteSheet sheet = new SpriteSheet(ImageLoader.ImageLoader("/textures/sheet.png"));
```

Here is Image Loader:

```
public class ImageLoader 
{
public ImageLoader()
{

}
public static BufferedImage ImageLoader(String path)
{
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

The two folders I have specified in the build path are src and res.
I know that it is building the images into the jar as i can see them if i extract it.

Any idea as to what I messed up on?

Comment: Open the jar, for instance with 7Zip or WinZip or eclipse. The path `"/textures/sheet.png"` should be there. Also it is case-sensitive (as opposed to Windows).

Comment: building as an executable jar just adds a single entry to the manifest file

Comment: The ImageLoader method should be named imageLoader.  The System.exit call should be removed from the imageLoader method.  If the textures directory is in the Java class path, the path name would be "/sheet.png".

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure u need to add a Res folder to the build path.

The Res folder is where all your sprite sheets should be.

Right click your project and edit build path.

**Try adding the textures folder to your build path**

**EDIT**
The folder doesn't need to be named "Res"

Comment: I have done that. See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/og0loomt8g5hm7m/6.jpg?dl=0)